# Creating adjacency matrix

Tags: r

I have a datastructure which looks like below

```
 id  year   club
"A" "2010" "C1"
"B" "2010" "C1"
"C" "2010" "C2"
"A" "2011" "C1"
"B" "2011" "C2"
```

etc. My problem is to create a matrix on a year by year basis where the each unique individual is fixed to a row and each unique club is fixed to a column. If in a given year the individual visits the club the corresponding intersecting cell takes the value of 1 else 0.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks 
Anup

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you want here. Can you maybe provide a sample of how your output should look? I'm having trouble picturing how an "adjacency matrix" applies to this problem.

Comment: Hi David. I'm actually having trouble trying to format the data. Maybe the term adjacency matrix is incorrect here. What I'm trying to do is set unique ids as rows and unique clubs as columns. If an id visits a club then the intersecting cell takes the value 1 or 0 otherwise. But I have to do this on a year by year basis. I hope this is clearer

Comment: When you say "year by year," do you want a separate matrix for each year, or do you want to count the number of years (or times) an id visits each club?

Comment: No I need separate matrices for each year stacked one after the other. Therefore if we make two matrices for 2010 and 2011, then i guess I need to rbind(mat1, mat2).

Comment: Please give us an example of what you expect the solution to look like.  You lack the language, which is ok, but use an alternative method to convey what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one-line solution outputs a single dataframe instead of separate matrices like the other solutions thus far posted. It requires the `reshape2` package, which if you've never used it before is extremely useful for this sort of thing.

```
require(reshape2)

df = data.frame(id=c('a','b','c','a','b')
               ,year=c(2010,2010,2010,2011,2011)
               ,club=c('c1','c1','c2','c1','c2')  
                )

result = dcast(df, year + id ~ club, fun.aggregate=length, drop=F)

> result

  year id c1 c2
1 2010  a  1  0
2 2010  b  1  0
3 2010  c  0  1
4 2011  a  1  0
5 2011  b  0  1
6 2011  c  0  0  # If you don't want this record, use: drop=T
```

Comment: Maybe add a `drop = FALSE` to your `dcast` in case unused levels are to be kept (as with year = 2011 and id = c).

Comment: @AnandaMahto Good call

Answer (score 3):

In base R, I would use `by` and `xtabs`:

```
by(dat, dat$year, with, as.matrix(xtabs(~ id + club) * 1L))
```

It returns a list of matrices (one per year). Also, I would recommend not multiplying by `1L` to return matrices of booleans.

---

Edit1: as suggested, you can also create a contingency table quite easily:

```
table(dat[c("id", "club", "year")])
```

---

Edit2: I see your comment to Ricardo's answer, maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(year, id), with, 1L * (table(club) > 0))
#   year id C1 C2
# 1 2010  A  1  0
# 2 2010  B  1  0
# 3 2010  C  0  1
# 4 2011  A  1  0
# 5 2011  B  0  1
```

You might also want to use `.drop = FALSE` to get all (6) possible year/id combinations:

```
ddply(dat, .(year, id), with, 1L * (table(club) > 0), .drop = FALSE)
#   year id C1 C2
# 1 2010  A  1  0
# 2 2010  B  1  0
# 3 2010  C  0  1
# 4 2011  A  1  0
# 5 2011  B  0  1
# 6 2011  C  0  0
```

Comment: If the LHS of the formula is empty, you can also use `table` in place of `xtabs` which will produce a contingency table of counts: `table(id, club)`

Comment: Why not `table(dat[c(1, 3, 2)])` or `ftable(dat, row.vars=c(2, 1), col.vars=3)`? Just curious...

Comment: Thank you very much folks. This is very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

based on the comments, suitable formats are either a three-dimensional array or a list of data.frames / data.tables.

```
    library(data.table)
DT <- data.table

### create a template matrix
# find all unique ID's and unique Club's
ids <- unique(DT$id)
clubs <- unique(DT$club)
# matrix template based on the number of ids & clubs
mat.template <- matrix(0L, nrow=length(ids), ncol=length(clubs), dimnames=list(ids, clubs))

# iterate over the unique values of year
DT <- data.table(dat, key="id,club")
res <- lapply(unique(DT$year), function(y) {
    # index the matrix by the DT where y == year. Set those values to 1
        mat <- copy(mat.template)
        mat[as.matrix(DT[y==year, list(id, club)])] <- 1
        mat
    })

setattr(res, "names", unique(DT$year))
```

#### Results:

```
res     

$`2010`
  C1 C2
A  1  0
B  1  0
C  0  1

$`2011`
  C1 C2
A  1  0
B  0  1
C  0  0
```

Comment: Note: There's a function `CJ` for `data.table` that performs the job of `expand.grid`.

Comment: Hi Ricardo. Thanks for the solution but it looks I did not specify my problem correctly. I have now edited the problem statement. The expand.grid option is not giving me the dummy variable output that I was looking for.

Comment: thanks @Arun, I always forget about CJ

Comment: Hi Ricardo. Great it works just fine. One last question. Is it possible for me to get this into a four column matrix where Column 1 is the year, column 2 is the ID and columns 3 and 4 represent the dummy variables?

Comment: @Anup. First try not to change your mind regarding a question. But more important, if you do, make that updated request inside your question, not as a comment to someone's answer.

Comment: @ flodel: I agree. I apologize for the confusion in the question. Next time I will post a question with the expected output. I think that would have solved the problem. My bad.

Comment: @anup, the first answer I posted was more in line with what you were looking for.  While flodel is correct, I would add that taking the time to think out your question will actually help clarify the problem for yourself as well as for others.  This will save a lot of time for all involved :)    Please don't let this deter you from asking more questions